# Contacting a user over a mistake in his answer

Tags: support

I'm sorry but I'm quite new to the inner workings of this site.

The answer from @fibonatic here:

[What is an intuitive explanation using forces for the equatorial bulge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108640/what-is-an-intuitive-explanation-using-forces-for-the-equatorial-bulge)

At the bottom it mentions that any value inbetween 0/90 degrees it would be positive, but this is untrue - just keep taking psi smaller until the second term in the denominator dominates. Unfortunately I can't comment to let him know since I lack reputation, can't PM since there is no function to, and I don't want to edit his answer because I don't know what the *right* answer is. I just want to make him aware so it gets changed correctly.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've [added a comment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108640/what-is-an-intuitive-explanation-using-forces-for-the-equatorial-bulge#comment406536_120189) to fibonatic about this meta post. He's still an active member, so he'll see this and (hopefully) correct misunderstandings (his or yours).

Comment: I have seen your question and updated my answer. I forgot to invert the radial component of the normal vector, which should point in the opposite direction of the total acceleration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you notice a mistake and know how to fix it, submit an edit to the answer.

If don't know how to fix it, leave a comment (requires 50 rep).

If you don't have enough rep to comment, ask someone who has enough rep to do it via [The h Bar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) (requires 20 rep).

If you don't have enough rep to use chat, answer or ask good questions to get more rep.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, but I disagree with the first (though I'm not downvoting your answer). Edits have to preserve the intent of the post. If everyone starts _fixing_ the mistakes that they see, and if these fixes are based on misunderstandings, the post changes for the worse. Of course, it may also lead to edit wars, with the post owner rolling back to press his point, and the user persisting with (which is especially bad if the editor has 2k+). IMO, the right way about it is your method no. 2, leave a comment. Post owner will see and act, or not act. But the comment will stay, so point stays noted.

Comment: ... I guess, like it is doing here! :P

Comment: @TheDarkSide I suppose in reality I usually only go for the first item if the fix is "obvious": typos, etc.